# How to run a command on every folder within a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Suppose that I have a directory structured like this:

```
project/
├── folder1/
│   └── mainline
|       └── ...
├── folder2/
│   └── mainline
|       └── ...
├── folder3/
│   └── mainline
|       └── ...
.
.
.
└──folderN/
    └── mainline
        └── ...
```

I want to run a command such as `ant clean` within every `mainline` folder. How can I do this?

Comment: Not 'on', but 'within'. I just changed the question, thanks for the correction. I'm not a native English speaker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you would want to run `ant clean` inside every `mainline` directory in the directory hierarchy that you show:

```sh
for mainline in project/folder*/mainline/; do
    ( cd "$mainline" && ant clean )
done
```

This would loop over the pathnames of each of the `mainline` directories.  For each such pathname, the body of the loop changes to that directory and runs `ant clean` within it.

The parentheses around the command in the loop runs those commands in a sub-shell.  The change of working directory is local to this sub-shell (we don't have to "step out of" the directory that we `cd` into).

---

If the `mainline` directories that you show are the *only* such directories, then you may use `find` like so:

```
find project -type d -name mainline -execdir sh -c 'cd mainline && ant clean' \;
```

This would find *any* directory called `mainline` in or under `project`, and then execute `ant clean` in each of these.  The `-execdir` action is non-standard but commonly implemented by the `find` utility on most Unices.

You could also look for the `build.xml` files that `ant` uses by default and execute `ant clean` in each `mainline` directory that contains such a file:

```
find project -type f -path '*/mainline/build.xml' -execdir ant clean \;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$ cd project/
$ find . -type d -name "mainline" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

This will find directories named "mainline" inside current folder(project/) and execute `ls -l` on each of them

Comment: You can optimize it using `+`.

Comment: This would pick up additional `mainline` directories not directly under the `folder*` directories, if such directories existed.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sure, but it is not specified to which level it goes. By looking at the question, this could be accepted as an answer.

Comment: It also does not run `ant clean` in the found directories...

Comment: Come on man, he said "such as and clean" and Im sure he knows how to replace ls -l with ant clean ffs

Comment: Replacing `ls -l` with `ant clean` would run e.g. `ant clean folder1/mainline`. They did specify that they wanted to run that command _within_ the `mainline` directory.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Kusalananda's answer is just  what I was looking for